# Filters in Spring Data Neo4j 4

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4

I am trying to use Neo4jOperations in Spring Data Neo4j 4.

Filters can be used in Neo4jOperations for retrieving data from NodeEntity.
Eg. I have a case where there are actors with "roles" in a movie. Now,Actor and Movie is a NodeEntity and roles is a RelationshipEntity. If i query a movie for a title using Filters, it does show me the relevant details.

I want to query details in the form - "Find me actors who have relationship (any relationship) in Movie 'Cloud Atlas'." I am not able to find a way to work for this using Filters.

Filters let you specify something like key-value pairs. Can I specify key value as "roles.movies.title" and query for the results?

Tried it this way, it does not work out.

Do not want to use Custom Query as we want to keep the query generic so that it can accomodate a lot of use cases. Attaching a custom query will mean that it can address only a specific case.

Comment: Sorry for digging out this old thread... but do you have found a reliable solution for this kind of dynamic filter queries?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement your own `FilterFunction`, however, much simpler is to use a custom query for this. Example:

```
@Query("MATCH (a:Actor)-[]-(n:Movie {name: "Cloud Atlas"}) return n")
public List<Actor> findActorsRelatedToCloudAtlas()
```

Comment: Do not want to use Custom Query as we want to keep the query generic so that it can accomodate a lot of use cases. Attaching a custom query will mean that it can address only a specific case.

Comment: To clarify: To do what you are asking is not presently supported with rerived finders.

Comment: In your knowledge, is there any other way to achieve this? Except custom query?

Comment: You can also use a FilterFunction as stated in the answer. No special support in derived finders.

Comment: shouldn't be 'return a' in the custom query? you want the actors, not the movies.